# Android : Creating GUI programmatically at run time in java

Tags: java, android, user-interface, dynamic

I have to create number of buttons and textbox, etc. depending upon a certain number. For ex: if the number = 5, I need to create 5 buttons, and if its value is 10, I need to create 10 buttons.

To achieve such a functionality, the conventional xml GUI won't make it up. I need to develop the GUI dynamically. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a Linear/Relative layout in xml and on run time according to given number add view(buttons and text views) in this layout.
See this tuts:
https://androiddesk.wordpress.com/2012/08/05/creating-dynamic-views-in-android/
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/09/android-dynamic-and-xml-layout.html

Comment: I want to do something similar to this. Can you please share some more details so that I could get an overview of what I need to code.

Comment: It depends on your requirement. See links in previous comment for basic idea and then do as per your need. In below example it will add a simple textview to layout.for(int i=0;i<number;++i){
 TextView tv=new TextView(con);
     
     tv.setText("Your Text");
     
 relative_layout.add(tv);
}

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at RecyclerView. You need to apply the DataSet (what u receive dynamclly) and then let the Adapter handle all of the Binding.
Take a look at this [tutorial](http://www.truiton.com/2015/02/android-recyclerview-tutorial/), there are many more.
Notice that you will need to create *TWO* Viewholder (button and a textview) and override the *getItemViewType*

Comment: It seems as an alternative to ListView. I need something which could render a complete GUI as we design it in xml manually.

Comment: Its much more abstract and effective then ListView. It should do the trick for u. If it doesnt then edit your question.